# How to addEventListener to future DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

File partial.html looks like this: `<button id="test">Hi I am from a partial!</button>`

`Partial.html` is dynamically included on the page, using `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open('get', 'partial.html', true);
oReq.send();
oReq.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#pageArea').innerHTML = this.response;
};
```

How can I add an event listener that will apply to future exisiting `#test` *without doing it after it's content has been loaded and inserted into `#pageArea`?*

**(No jQuery solutions, please!)**

Comment: You may need to parse HTML before browser does it. Why you need to do it before it has been loaded and inserted in DOM structure?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Events like *click* [bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing), so you attach the event handler to the closest non-dynamic parent, and inside the event handler you check if it was the button being clicked by seeing if it was the event's target :

```
var parent = document.getElementById('pageArea');

if (parent.addEventListener) {
    parent.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
}else if (parent.attachEvent) {
    parent.attachEvent('onclick', handler);
}

function handler(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'test') {
         // the button was clicked
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H97WY/)

Comment: Will this approach have any impact on performance? Is it not better to  attach the eventListener directly to the element?

Comment: @subZero - you can't attach an event handler to something that isn't there, that's why you have to delegate.

Comment: Always wondered how you might approach this in plain js (use jQuery .on when I need this). Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

**Don't *just* use `Event.target`**!
As wrongly suggested by many other answers I found online, an *Event.target* might well be an **undesired child element**!
Consider for example: `<button class="dynamic" type="button">CLICK <i>ME!</i></button>`
if you click on the *"ME!"* part of the button — your logic will fail miserably.

> **Always use `Event.target` in combination with `.closest()`**

```js
document.querySelector("#staticParent").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (event.target.closest(".dynamic")) {
    // The desired button (or its child) was clicked!
  }
});
```

### Creating your own `on()` and `off()` helper functions:

For **dynamically created elements** on whom you want to assign a click event before they are inserted in the DOM — assign the event to the parent **delegator**, and than query the Event `Event.target.closest(selector)` matches the desired **dynamic child** selector:

```js
const _ev = (type, name, delegator, ...arg) => {
  if (typeof delegator === "string") return document.querySelectorAll(delegator).forEach(el => _ev(type, name, el, ...arg));
  if (typeof arg[0] === "string") delegator[type](name, ev => ev.target.closest(arg[0]) && arg[1](ev), arg[2]);
  else delegator[type](name, arg[0], arg[1]);
};
const on = (...arg) => _ev("addEventListener", ...arg);
const off = (...arg) => _ev("removeEventListener", ...arg);


// Use like:

on("click", "#staticParent", ".dynamicChild", (ev) => {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget, ev.target);
});

on("click", ".test", (ev) => {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget);
}, { once: true });
```

```css
body * { padding: 0.5rem; background: #0002; margin: 0.2rEm; }
```

```html
<div id="staticParent"> Parent
  <div class="dynamicChild">Existent or dynamic Child (Clickable)</div>
</div>

<div class="test">Test 1 (I'm only clickable once)</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Roko's point about needing to check event.target is a good one. But the _ev function from that example doesn't actually seem to properly filter child nodes from the event.target (at least in my testing). To avoid the event.target problem mentioned I had to modify that example to explicitly check the target, like:

```
on("click", "#staticParent", ".dynamicChild", (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.closest(".dynamicChild")){
    // whatever you're trying have dynamic child do
  }
});
```

Otherwise, a child node within .dynamicChild will still overtake the event target.

Comment: That's already stated in my answer. Twice. But yes, this more explicitly proves what's already underlined. If an improvement was necessary you could've  point that out in a single comment.

Comment: I was just pointing out that your answer explained the common pitfal, showed how to fix the common pitfall, but then provided a great example solution to the original question (of registering event listeners for future DOM elements) that is still susceptible to the event target problem. Can't really post multi-line code examples in a comment, which is why I posted an "answer" because it was easier to show than to try and explain in a comment. Not trying to ruffle feathers - just trying to help future people who stumble upon this answer understand what they're looking at.