# Javascript pan and wheel zoom image

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming, mousewheel

I have the following code used for panning image. Panning works well, but wheel zoom not. When  I start zooming anywhere above the image I want it to zoom from that cursor point outwards. Currently image moves from the mouse.

```js
var mouseX,
  mouseY,
  mouseTX,
  mouseTY,
  panning = false,
  panEventAdded,
  ts = {
    scale: 1,
    translate: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  }


var boxChildWrap = document.querySelector(".aplbox-child");

addPanEvents()

function addPanEvents() {

  panEventAdded = true;

  boxChildWrap.onpointerdown = pointerdownHandler;

  boxChildWrap.onpointerup = pointerupHandler;
  boxChildWrap.onpointercancel = pointerupHandler;
  boxChildWrap.onpointerout = pointerupHandler;
  boxChildWrap.onpointerleave = pointerupHandler;
  document.onpointerup = pointerupHandler;

}

function pointerdownHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


  panning = true;

  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
  mouseTX = ts.translate.x;
  mouseTY = ts.translate.y;

  boxChildWrap.onpointermove = pointermoveHandler
};

function pointermoveHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let rec = boxChildWrap.getBoundingClientRect();

  const x = e.clientX;
  const y = e.clientY;

  if (!panning) {
    return;
  }

  ts.translate.x = mouseTX + (x - mouseX);
  ts.translate.y = mouseTY + (y - mouseY);

  setTransform();

};

function pointerupHandler(e) {
  panning = false;
  boxChildWrap.onpointermove = null
}

function setTransform() {
  const transform = 'translate(' + ts.translate.x + 'px,' + ts.translate.y + 'px) scale(' + ts.scale + ') translate3d(0,0,0)';
  boxChildWrap.style.transform = transform;
  boxChildWrap.style.transition = '';
}

boxChildWrap.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {

  var xs = (e.clientX - ts.translate.x) / ts.scale,
    ys = (e.clientY - ts.translate.y) / ts.scale,
    delta = (e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta : -e.deltaY);
  (delta > 0) ? (ts.scale *= 1.2) : (ts.scale /= 1.2);

  ts.translate.x = e.clientX - xs * ts.scale;
  ts.translate.y = e.clientY - ys * ts.scale;

  setTransform();

})
```

```css
.aplbox-child {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: transform;
  touch-action: none;
}

.aplbox-child img {
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aplbox-child aplbox-image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1280/720"></div>
```

Comment: A big UX issue is in that you're assigning events to the same element you're panning and scaling. Events should come from a parent element. Imagine (theoretically) that your image is scaled to a really small size of 10×5 px. Congratulations now the user needs to pin-point that small element in order to mousewheel etc. Seems like this should be brought back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

- Your handler events should originate from a parent, not from the  element you need to resize. This way you'll drastically improve the UI/UX.
- All the calculations should be relative to the canvas center
- Use a constant scale factor
- Use scale min / max values, to prevent the *canvas* getting too small, large

Here's your code (with a slightly modified HTML as well) with some additional functions taken from the [**ZoomPan** project](https://github.com/rokobuljan/zoompan)

```js
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);
const clamp = (val, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(val, min), max);

const elViewport = el(".aplbox");
const elCanvas = el(".aplbox-child", elViewport);

const ts = {
  scale: 1,
  scaleMin: 0.2,
  scaleMax: 6,
  scaleFactor: 0.2,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

/**
 * Get client size and position of viewport
 * @returns {object} {width,height,x,y} of the viewport Element
 */
const getViewport = () => {
  return elViewport.getBoundingClientRect();
};

/**
 * Get canvas size and position relative to viewport
 * @returns {object} {width,height,x,y} of the (scaled) canvas Element
 */
const getCanvas = () => {
  const vpt = getViewport();
  const width = elCanvas.offsetWidth * ts.scale;
  const height = elCanvas.offsetHeight * ts.scale;
  const x = (vpt.width - width) / 2 + ts.x;
  const y = (vpt.height - height) / 2 + ts.y;
  return { width, height, x, y };
};

/**
 * Get pointer origin XY from pointer position
 * relative to canvas center
 * @param {PointerEvent|Object} ev Event with x,y pointer coordinates of Object {x,y}
 * @return {object} {originX, originY} offsets from canvas center
 */
const getPointerOrigin = ({ x, y }) => {
  const vpt = getViewport();
  const cvs = getCanvas();
  const originX = x - vpt.x - cvs.x - cvs.width / 2;
  const originY = y - vpt.y - cvs.y - cvs.height / 2;
  return { originX, originY }
};

/** Apply transforms to canvas */ 
const transform = () => {
  elCanvas.style.scale = ts.scale;
  elCanvas.style.translate = `${ts.x}px ${ts.y}px`;
};

/**
 * Apply a new scale at a given origin point relative from canvas center
 * Useful when zooming in/out at a specific "anchor" point.
 * @param {number} scaleNew 
 * @param {number} originX Scale to X point (relative to canvas center)
 * @param {number} originY Scale to Y point (relative to canvas center) 
 */
const scaleTo = (scaleNew = 1, originX, originY) => {
  scaleNew = clamp(scaleNew, ts.scaleMin, ts.scaleMax);
  const scaleOld = ts.scale;

  // Calculate the XY as if the element is in its
  // original, non-scaled size: 
  const xOrg = originX / scaleOld;
  const yOrg = originY / scaleOld;

  // Calculate the scaled XY 
  const xNew = xOrg * scaleNew;
  const yNew = yOrg * scaleNew;

  // Retrieve the XY difference to be used as the change in offset:
  const xDiff = originX - xNew;
  const yDiff = originY - yNew;

  ts.scale = scaleNew;
  ts.x = ts.x + xDiff;
  ts.y = ts.y + yDiff
  
  transform();
};


// Event handlers

const pointerDownHandler = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  elViewport.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId);
  elViewport.addEventListener("pointermove", pointerMoveHandler);
  elViewport.addEventListener("pointerup", pointerUpHandler);
}; 

const pointerMoveHandler = (evt) => {
  ts.x += evt.movementX;
  ts.y += evt.movementY;
  transform();
};

const pointerUpHandler = (evt) => {
  elViewport.releasePointerCapture(evt.pointerId);
  elViewport.removeEventListener("pointermove", pointerMoveHandler);
  elViewport.removeEventListener("pointerup", pointerUpHandler);
};

const scaleHandler = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  const delta = Math.sign(-evt.deltaY);
  const scaleNew = ts.scale * Math.exp(delta * ts.scaleFactor);
  const {originX, originY} = getPointerOrigin(evt);
  scaleTo(scaleNew, originX, originY);
};

elViewport.addEventListener("pointerdown", pointerDownHandler);
elViewport.addEventListener("wheel", scaleHandler);
```

```css
.aplbox {
  position: relative;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}

.aplbox-child {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  touch-action: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.aplbox-child img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="aplbox">
  <div class="aplbox-child">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1280/720">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, mabye attaching event to parent is a better idea. In any case, I should add drag limits as well. Btw, you code is missing something like document.onpointerup = pointerupHandler; because if you drag outside then let go, drag can stick to mouse.

Comment: it doesn't stick to mouse in my case

Comment: Yes @Toniq sorry for not doing that immediately. Actually, you should not bloat the document with additional listeners. That's achieved using [set/releasePointerCapture()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setPointerCapture). Nicely found, edited my answer.

Comment: @FlashThunder that's because I've edited my answer since :D but thanks for confirming that it's fixed ;)

Comment: I was not aware of setPointerCapture. But I guess you cannot use setPointerCapture to listen for click events on elements created in the future so you have to attach listeners to document?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809473/1009466

Comment: @Toniq that answer of mine you linked to is not related to pointerCapture. I'm not sure what is the problem with click events on future elements. What future elements are you referring to?